# What part of this code will execute on Spark driver?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM")

def getEventCountOnWeekdaysPerMonth(data: RDD[(LocalDateTime, Long)]): Array[(String, Long)] = {

 val result = data
   .filter(e => e._1.getDayOfWeek.getValue < DayOfWeek.SATURDAY.getValue)
   .map(mapDateTime2Date)
   .reduceByKey(_ + _)
   .collect()

 result
   .map(e => (e._1.format(formatter), e._2))
}

private def mapDateTime2Date(v: (LocalDateTime, Long)): (LocalDate, Long) = {
 (v._1.toLocalDate.withDayOfMonth(1), v._2)
}
```

In the above code piece, data stored in "result" will be sent to driver during execution because of collect.
 Will the mapping on "result" take place on driver or executors will also store the "result" and perform the mapping and store it till next action is called ?

Comment: No, the `map` will be executed in the **driver** because it is a normal **Scala** `Array`. If you latter need that result on the **executors**, then you can broadcast it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execution on driver, in which case next Action is not relevant. collect means result set on driver and futher processing there. Would need makeRDD or equivalent for map to push processing to executors.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, nothing is executed here because there are only method declarations (besides of the formatter). If you call `getEventCountOnWeekdaysPerMonth`, only this line will be executed on the driver :

```
result
  .map(e => (e._1.format(formatter), e._2))
```

This is because `result` is a plain scala array.

Comment: Yes these methods are being called from main, I have involved only the relevant portion, does result being plain scala array changes anything ?